# What is the probability of a random line passing through the unit disk meet the y-axis?

Tags: probability, euclidean-geometry

This is a question that I came up myself. So it might have some of the errors pointed in the comments below.

Consider the open unit disk centered at (0,0) and the set of all straight lines of the plane that intersect the y-axis. Hence, we are consedering the set of straight lines that have the form: y=lx+m, $l\in\mathbb{R}, m\in\mathbb{R}$. What is the probability of a randomly selected line that passes through the unit disk to intesect the y-axis inside the unit disk?

I don't really know how to approach this kind of problems. At first I try to see which lines pass through the unit disk. The coefficients must obey $|m|<\sqrt{l^2+1}$. To intersect the y-axis inside the unit disk we must have $|m|<1$. Thus, for a fixed $l\in\mathbb{R}$ the proportion of the lines that meet the y-axis inside the unit disk is $1/\sqrt{l^2+1}$ (lenght of (-1,1)/ length of $(-\sqrt(l^2+1),\sqrt(l^2+1))$. Now the probability must be the mean value of $1/\sqrt{l^2+1}$
for $l\in(-\infty,+\infty)$, which is the integral of this function over that interval. But the integral

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{l^2+1}}=\infty.$$

Hence, this reasoning - which seems right to me - doesn't lead to an answer. I don't really know how to approach this kind of problems.
Do you have any hints? Suggestions? Or maybe an answer?

Comment: What is the probability distribution for the lines?

Comment: I believe the problem here is that we're assuming a uniform distribution on the slope, but this isn't possible because the slope is unbounded. It likely makes more sense to work with $l = \tan(\theta)$ and $\theta \sim U(-\frac\pi 2, \frac\pi 2)$

Comment: And what is $m$'s distribution? Note that a uniform distribution cannot be defined on the whole real line.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to define the lines by their angle relative to the $y$ axis rather than slope. That way the straight vertical lines are included for completeness, and we get an easy uniform distribution on $(0,\pi)$. That is if OP is trying to define this problem on their own rather than being given it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I have not been given this question, I asked it for myself.

Comment: In order to answer such questions one needs to define distribution law. Example: Let's take all real numbers $x$ such that $1<x<5$. What is probability that $x < 4$? One may think answer is $\frac34$ but it's wrong. Correct answer depends on distribution law of random variable $x$. One can consider uniform distribution of real numbers as 'default'. Then answer will be $\frac34$. But there is no 'default' distribution of lines passing unit disk, so you should define distribution law explicitly. If the line are uniformly distributed in $l$ and $m$ then answer is zero.

Comment: $P=\lim_{A\to \infty} \frac{\int_{-A}^{A} \frac{1}{\sqrt{l^2+1}}dl}{\int_{-A}^{A} 1\;dl}=\lim_{A\to \infty} \frac{{\rm arcsinh}\; A}{A}=0$

Comment: I assume what is meant is this: Randomly choose a point in the circle based on area . In other words, split the circle up into tiny squares of equal area. Then make it so that the probability of our point going through being in any particular square is the same as the probability as it being in another square. Then we are going to let the area of the squares tend to $0$.

Independently, we let the angle that the line makes to the horizontal, $\theta,$ be chosen uniformly from $[0,\pi).$

The problem with this, I think, is that choosing which square and choosing theta aren't independent.

Comment: In other words, if we use the method I describe, then the probability of some lines (in particular, lines going through the centre of the circle, or near the centre of a quadrant) being chosen are greater than the probability of other lines being chosen (for example, lines that cut the circle into a large arc and a tiny arc).

Answer (score 2):

It's better to think of the lines in terms of their angle of approach. Fundamentally the probability of a line intersecting the $y$ axis is the area of the central four sided figure swept out by sliding a particularly angled line left or right until it's intersection with the axis lies outside the disk.

The area of a segment of a circle i.e. the "cap" of a sector cut off by a chord is given by

$$\frac{\beta-\sin\beta}{2}$$

where $\beta$ is the angle substended by the arc as measured from the center of the circle. This angle and the angle of attack of the lines (as measured from the $y$ axis) form an equilateral triangle giving the area of that segment as

$$\frac{\pi-2\theta - \sin2\theta}{2}$$

Since there are two of these segments outside the area swept out by the circle, the probability we want is the area of the full circle minus twice this segment.

$$P(\theta) = \frac{2\theta+\sin2\theta}{\pi}$$

where the resultant is normalized by the total area. This formula is only valid until the angle reaches $\pi/2$, at which point the distribution is symmetric and will retreat back to $0$ towards $\pi$.

Using $\Theta \sim U(0,\pi)$ we can now compute the integral

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{[0,\pi]}P(\theta)d\theta = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2\theta+\sin2\theta}{\pi}d\theta = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi^2}$$

Comment: Please check your answer, I think it is wrong, I just read the following theorem in Santalos's Integral Geometry which discusses the topic of a line meeting a convex set. The theorem asserts that, if $K_1\subset K$ are 2 convex sets, then the probability that a random line intersects $K_1$ if it is known that it intersects $K$ is $L_1/L$ where $L_1$ and $L$ are the perimeters of the convex sets. Now the perimeter of the unit disk is $2\pi$ and the perimeter of the line segment $[(0,-1),(0,1)]$ (which is a convex set) is $4$. Hence, $4/2\pi=2/\pi$ and I can justify that value with 2 < ways.

Comment: The theorem is in page 30 of Santalo's "Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability" 1976